# Use of Weierstrass or parametric formulas in the identities

Tags: trigonometry, soft-question, education

We know that the formulas of Weierstrass or named also **parametric formulas** (obviously true in their domain of definition) are:

$$\tan \left(\frac \alpha2\right):=t, \quad \sin(\alpha)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2},\, \cos(\alpha)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} \tag 1$$

We suppose that we have these examples of identities:

$$\tan \left(\frac \alpha2\right)=\csc(\alpha)-\cot(\alpha) \tag 2$$
$$\tan \left(\frac \pi4-\frac \alpha2\right)=\frac{\cos(\alpha)}{1+\sin(\alpha)}\tag 3$$

I have suggest to my students to use the Weiestrass' formulas to have an equation in function of $t$ because there are not squares in $(2)$ and $(3)$ (or we not seen any square of a trigonometric functions in function of $\alpha/2$ - for example).

In fact I have given a suggestion to never use the formulas $(5)$,

$$\sin (\alpha)=\pm \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(\alpha)}{2}}, \quad \cos (\alpha)=\pm \sqrt{\frac{1+\cos(\alpha)}{2}} \tag 5$$

because we not know the value of $\alpha$.

**My question:**

> Do you think (for $(2)$ and $(3)$) is the best alternative to use Weierstrass formulas when we see goniometric operators as a function of half angle $\alpha/2$ and to $\alpha$ in the identities?

Comment: I suspect by "goniometric operators" you mean what we call in English, "trigonometric functions." Also by "not use never" I think you mean "never use." The formulas in (1) clearly have squares in them, why would you say they don't? Or, when you say the Weierstrass formulas don't have squares, were you instead referring to (2) and (3)? In your question, when you ask if "it" is the best alternative, does "it" refer to (2),(3) or does it refer to the formulas in your fourth line?

Comment: @runway44 Hi, correct suspect! :-)...I'm sorry for my poor English language.